# How can i get lines of code / fetch declaration in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, metaprogramming

Hi can anyone tell me that how can I fetch lines of code from C# code.
For example, I have following code in c#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MyCodeHelp
{
    class MultiplicationProgram
    {
        public int Multiplication(int Firstnumber, int SecondNumber)
        {
            int Result = (Firstnumber * SecondNumber);
            return Result;
        }
    }
}
```

So please tell me how can I fetch the following code from the code above and display it in a label or panel?

```
public int Multiplication(int Firstnumber, int SecondNumber)
{
    int Result = (Firstnumber * SecondNumber);
    return Result;
}
```

Comment: Put the code in a text file and read the text file, then write the text to your control.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking.  What do you mean by "get lines of code"?  Are you just trying to read the `.cs` file?

Comment: It really can't be done reliably, since the source code may no longer be available at the time the application is executed.  I think your best hope may be to include the source code as a resource in your compiled assembly.

Comment: @recursive, MsBuild does make this easy: `<Target Name="CodeAsResource" BeforeTargets="BeforeBuild"><ItemGroup><EmbeddedResource Include="@(Compile)" /></ItemGroup></Target>`

Comment: @Mitch:  In that case, this may be more possible than I assumed.  I suppose you still need some way to parse the file at run-time to identify the method you're looking for.

Comment: yes David i want read .cs file and display code/lines of code to panel.

Comment: how can i fetch that lines of code from .cs file and display to panel?

Comment: @recursive, yeah... I'm entertained by the idea of compiling code with Roslyn to reflect code it's own code using Roslyn.  That or using the pdb's.  Practically speaking, it makes more sense to just include the snippet as a resource (rather than the entire source code), but it is a fun thought.

Comment: @user3807530 did my answer solve your problem, if so could you tick it as answered, thanks.

Comment: @Seano666 - why even do that? cs file is text file already

Answer (score 2):

Get your panel/label name and just do this:

```
labelName.Text = Result.ToString();
```

Comment: I wasn't too sure what you was asking for but thats what I think you was asking for...

Answer (score 1):

You cannot get the code from the compiled dll, you have to include the code as a resource or as loose files.  One way to do this is to add an MSBuild step that causes all `Compile` items to be embedded as `EmbeddedResource`s.

In your `.csproj` file, add the below to the end:

Before:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="14.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <!-- ... -->
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
</Project>
```

After:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="14.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <!-- ... -->
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
  <Target Name="CodeAsResource" BeforeTargets="BeforeBuild">
    <ItemGroup>
      <EmbeddedResource Include="@(Compile)" />
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>
</Project>
```

Then you can access it as a resource:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Resources;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Codeception
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var code = getcode("Program.cs");

            Console.WriteLine(code);
        }

        private static string getcode(string filename)
        {
            using (var sr = new StreamReader(typeof(Program).Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("Codeception." + filename)))
            {
                return sr.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example:

```
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string filePath = @"";

        using (var sr = new StreamReader(filePath))
        {
            string line;

            while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                label1.Text += "\n" + line;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, I imagine you want to fetch some lines from the source code you wrote, right?

First of all, you need to ship your code (or a text copy of your code) with your binaries, and put it in a known path.

Then, you can Open the file with File.OpenText method (example in https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.opentext(v=vs.110).aspx ).

To get specific content from the file (which is the StreamReader you received as return from OpenText method), you can call ReadLine method (example in https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.readline(v=vs.110).aspx) and search wit String compares (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.compare(v=vs.110).aspx) if you found the piece of code you are looking for.

If you are thinking of changing the code later, I recommend you put the code you would like to share inside a "region" tag (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9a1ybwek.aspx). This way you can look for that region specifically, and you don't need to worry about changing your code.

I hope I could help you.